# Frenzied Rage as Wild Shape Elemental

Tags: dnd-5e, druid, wild-shape, barbarian, rage

I just noticed something while looking at the stat card of the *fire elemental* - it, and the 3 other elementals for that matter, are immune to *exhaustion*.

> Condition Immunities: Exhaustion, [...]

Now, at druid level 10, you can spend 2 uses of *Wild Shape* to turn into one of these elementals.

At *Path of the Berserker* barbarian level 3, you can go into a *Frenzied Rage* to make a melee weapon attack as a bonus action on each of your turns until the rage ends (emphasis mine):

> Starting when you choose this path at 3rd level, you can go into a frenzy when you rage. If you do so, for the duration of your rage you can make a single melee weapon attack as a bonus action on each of your turns after this one. **When your rage ends, you suffer one level of exhaustion** (as described in Appendix A).

Since the description of *Wild Shape* states the following:

> You retain the benefit of any features from your class, race, or other source and can use them if the new form is physically capable of doing so.

#### Therefore, am I correct to assume that if your rage ends while you are in elemental form - regardless of whether you started the rage as an elemental or switched during the rage - you do *not* take one point of exhaustion?

(Using *Wild Shape* during a rage should be possible since it's not a spell and doesn't require concentration)

And also, would you even gain the benefits of a *Frenzied Rage* while in elemental form? I mean, nothing states that they use a bonus action for any of their attacks, and they have multiattack (all 4 types), so you could technically make three *Slam* or *Touch* attacks (depending on the elemental), right? Both *Slam*  and *Touch* are listed as *Melee weapon attacks*.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## You would not gain exhaustion

If you gain immunity to a condition , that condition ends. Jeremy Crawford makes [this statement](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/736269988885995521) about conditions:

> In [D&D], the exceptional trumps the general. (No longer being a valid target trumps condition carryover.)

Since you are no longer valid for exhaustion, any exhaustion is removed and you cannot acquire exhaustion.

## Multiattack

You could indeed make the slam or touch attack with this as a bonus action. Attacks with natural weapons still count as melee weapon attacks despite the natural weapons not qualifying as weapons per se.

You could not, however (as you realize), take the multiattack action as it is not a Melee Weapon Attack.

Comment: no, I didn't mean taking the Multiattack as a bonus action. But you can use Multiattack as your action, then make another melee weapon attack as a bonus, which results in 3 attacks (as written above).
Also, I don't believe turning into an elemental would *remove existing* exhaustion, since *your* body is exhausted, while just the elemental form gets immunity. Whereas when you frenzy-rage as elemental, the elemental would be exhausted (which is impossible).

Comment: I know it makes sense that your existing exhaustion remains but RAW you will lose it. Conditions don't care what form your in. If a condition is ineligible, it's gone. I meant that I realize you know you cannot make multiattack a a bonus action. I'll clarify